# Get desired value from this with json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am still trying to get my head around json.loads and json.dumps to extract what I want from a web page. I am after some data from this [link](http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/) that takes the format of:

```
data:{
                url: 'stage-player-stat'
            },
            defaultParams: {
                stageId: 9155,
                teamId: 32,
                playerId: -1,
                field: 2
            },
```

The code I am using is this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time
import re
import json
import requests

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/"]

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\Teams'),deny=(),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        stagematch = re.compile("data:\s*{\s*url:\s*'stage-player-stat'\s*},\s*defaultParams:\s*{\s*(.*?),.*},",re.S)

        stagematch2 = re.search(stagematch, response.body)

        if stagematch2 is not None:
            stagematch3 = stagematch2.group(1)


            stageid = json.dumps(stagematch3)

            print "stageid = ", stageid

    execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal2'])
```

In this example, `stageId` resolves to `"stageId: 9155"`. What I want it to resolve to though is `9155`. I have tried to parse `stageId` with `stageid = stageid[0]` as if it is a dictionary, but this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `json.dumps` at all. Scrapy will have parsed the content and extracted the data. Why do you want to convert it to JSON, only to then try and extract data from that JSON? Why not just return `stagematch3` as it is?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes you are right, stagematch3 returns stageId: 9155 without quotes, however i just want 9155 returned. what is the last line of code i need? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stagematch3 = stagematch2.group(1)
stageid = int(stagematch3.split(':', 1)[1])
```

Then you may convert it back to str if you wish:

```
stageid = str(stageid)
```

There are many other ways to solve your problem. One of them is using a simpler regexp and then parsing the match object with `json.loads`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [js2xml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/js2xml):

- get all `<script>` contents
- parse each with js2xml: you get a lxml tree back
- using XPath on the lxml document, look for a `var defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams` and get it's init `object`
- use `js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict()` to get a Python `dict` out of it

Here's how it goes, illustrated in this scrapy shell session:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/
2014-09-08 11:17:31+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
...
2014-09-08 11:17:32+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f88f0605990>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f88f6046450>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x7f88efdaff50>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [1]: import pprint

In [2]: import js2xml

In [3]: for script in response.xpath('//script/text()').extract():
    jstree = js2xml.parse(script)
    params = jstree.xpath('//var[@name="defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams"]/object')
    if params:
        pprint.pprint(js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict(params[0]))
   ...:         
{'data': {'url': 'stage-player-stat'},
 'defaultParams': {'field': 2, 'playerId': -1, 'stageId': 9155, 'teamId': 32},
 'fitText': {'container': '.grid .team-link, .grid .player-link',
             'options': {'width': 150}},
 'fixZeros': True}

In [4]: for script in response.xpath('//script/text()').extract():
    jstree = js2xml.parse(script)
    params = jstree.xpath('//var[@name="defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams"]/object')
    if params:
        params = js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict(params[0])
   ...:         print params["defaultParams"]["stageId"]
   ...:         
9155

In [5]:
```

Comment: thanks for this, this looks really good. i've not tried it yet, but i will do and let you know how i got on.